# why there is 'unhashable type: 'set''

Tags: python, pandas

```py
train_df = pd.read_csv('./datas/TADPOLE_D1_D2.csv')
selected_features = pd.read_csv('./datas/EMCEB_features.csv')['feature'].values.tolist()
features = selected_features[:200]
features += ['RID', 'Diagnosis', 'Ventricles_ICV']
features = set(features)
train_df = train_df.copy()[features]
train_df.info()
```

I get the following error

```
      2 features += ['RID', 'Diagnosis', 'Ventricles_ICV']
      3 features = set(features)
----> 4 train_df = train_df.copy()[features]
      5 train_df.info()
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

there are all `str` elements in the `features`,then, I transform the 'set' to 'list', it normally runs.

```
features = list(set(features))
train_df = train_df.copy()[features]
```

so why 'pd.dataframe' can't use the 'set' slice index to get data?

Comment: You should instead use `frozenset`

Comment: @PatrickArtner They later say that they use a list to index successfully, and that's not hashable, so that's not exactly the reason. I think the actual reason is simply that pandas doens't support indexing in that way.

Comment: @Arthur Tacca It may be so, I browse the  [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data), there is no `set` used as indexer.